# What is the best way to combine sklearn classifiers that are trained separately?

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, ensemble-learning

Here's the scenario :
I want to combine three scikit learn classifiers (ex: 3 SVM classifiers) that are trained with diferent data, but the final model (the one that would actually predict instances) needs to be a ensemble/stacking or a modelo that simply takes into account the three auxiliar classifiers.

Let the classifiers be SVM1, SVM2 and SVM3 and the available subsets of training TS1,TS2 and TS3.
SVM1 will be fitted with TS1;
SVM2 will be fitted with TS2;
and SVM3 will be fitted with TS3.

The final model, that will predict new instances, needs to be an ensemble of SVM1,SVM2 and SVM3.
I don't want to fit all the 3 auxiliar methods with the same data. I want to divide the entire training data into subsets (TS1,TS2,TS3) and fit each auxiliar classifier with a diferent subset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you had 1 dataset and 3 `SVM` models, you could have used `Voting Regressor` from `Scikit-Learn` which will train 3 different `SVM` models on same data and combine them by taking average of their prediction. But you want to train 3 `SVM` models on 3 different dataset, the you have to vote them yourself. like this:

```
model1 = SVR()
model2 = SVR()
model3= SVR()

model1.fit(TS1_x, TS1_y)
model2.fit(TS2_x, TS2_y)
model3.fit(TS3_x, TS3_y)

pred1 = model1.predict(test)
pred2 = model2.predict(test)
pred3 = model3.predict(test)

finalpred = (pred1 + pred2 + pred3) / 3
```